# Passing a list through a LIKE operator in SQL (SSMS)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table of company info (name, HQ country, etc) and a list of country names.

I want to see which companies have a country name in their company name, but ARE NOT headquartered in that country.

I have a simple SQL query to do it one at a time, but I want to write a query that passes all countries through.

Right now my where clause effectively looks like

```
WHERE company LIKE '%CANADA%'
  AND hq_country_full != 'CANADA'
```

I tried using a subquery as well but could not figure this one out.  I'm thinking I probably need to use a local variable but not sure how to set it up. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Why not use a  left join on those two tables instead?

Comment: Is your "list of country names" a separate table?

Comment: Ah, your looking for VITALY SHOES that is not in Italy and FRANCESCO'S STORE that is not in France. Good luck :-)

Answer (score 2):

Something like this, perhaps?

```
declare @Company table (company varchar(128), hq_country_full varchar(128));
insert @Company values
    ('Canada Company', 'Canada'),
    ('Non-Canada Company', 'Mexico'),
    ('Mexico Company', 'Mexico'),
    ('Non-Mexico Company', 'Canada');

declare @Country table (country varchar(128));
insert @Country values
    ('Canada'),
    ('Mexico');

select
    Company.*
from
    @Company Company
where
    exists (select 1 from @Country Country where 
        Company.hq_country_full != Country.country and
        Company.company like '%' + Country.country + '%');
```

Results:

```
company              hq_country_full
Non-Canada Company   Mexico
Non-Mexico Company   Canada
```

I've opted for a semi-join (`exists`) rather than a left join because it's theoretically possible that a company could satisfy the criterion you described for multiple countries, and I supposed that you'd only want the country to appear in the result set once in such a case. If you want multiple results in that case, use a left join instead.

Comment: hey this looks promising!  I'm unfamiliar with this type of sql but i'm assuming you can run a select for the insert so that I don't have to manually type out 80 million+ rows?  I think I found my solution but I'm interested in this approach, as mine isn't 100% airtight

Comment: @EthanE - The purpose of my `DECLARE` and `INSERT` statements is just to set up some sample data since I didn't have your original tables to work with. You wouldn't need them at all, assuming this data is already in your database somewhere. Just use something like my `SELECT`, with `@Country` and `@Company` replaced with your actual table names.

Answer (score 1):

You could put that list with country names in a table. That can even be a #temporary table or a @table variable.

After that you can just join the company info table to the country names table with a LIKE.

```
-- Using a table variable for the example
declare @countrynames table (name varchar(80) primary key);
insert into @countrynames (name) values
 ('CANADA')
,('BELGIUM')
,('RUSSIA')
,('USA');


SELECT 
 comp.company, 
 comp.hq_country_full
 ctry.name as countryName
FROM companyinfo comp 
JOIN @countrynames as ctry
  ON comp.company LIKE '%'+ctry.name+'%'
WHERE comp.hq_country_full != ctry.name
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like since you have a hq_country_full column, you can use that in the LIKE clause:

```
WHERE company NOT LIKE '%' + hq_country_full + '%'
```